# Dynamic name of Spark notebook in Notebook activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm implementing an integration pipeline in Azure Synapse Analytics and I want to call Synapse Spark notebooks in a ForEach loop using dynamic naming based on the parameter in the Items setting. I can't find a way to this, like you can when calling a Databricks notebook. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: the same question from me, any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post, I never knew that the notebook activity behavers differently then the Adb activity .
Please consider using an If activity which lets you branch out based on parameter values.